# Change Notepad to Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I want to make it so that if I enter "notepad" in a command line, the address bar, or in the start menu search, it will open Notepad++ instead of Notepad.

Is there a simple, safe, stable way to implement this?

Comment: Notepad is a pre installed program that comes with windows, there is no path and it can only run notepad because it is in the same folder as cmd.exe i'm not sure about changing the name.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.binaryfortress.com/NotepadReplacer/ is the simplest way I found years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Files started from the command line etc. that don't have a path specified will use the path specified in your $PATH variable.  The order that paths appear in the $PATH variable matter - the ones at the front are tried first.

So if you have a file named `notepad.bat` in your path, AND that path appears in your $PATH before `C:\Windows\System32`, it will get called before `notepad.exe`.

So:

- Create a file called `notepad.bat`.  The only line in it should be: `notepad++`.
- Place it in a folder (e.g., `C:\Scripts`).
- Add that folder to the BEGINNING of your path: `path C:\Scripts;%PATH%`

Comment: Citing a source for the path order mattering: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723564.aspx#XSLTsection127121120120

Comment: Put it in your answer, use appropriate format codes

Answer (score 0):

If you have notepad++ installed on your computer, you can go into the directory file where notepad++ is installed on your computer and drag the Icon onto your taskbar in windows so that you can have a link to the program whenever your computer is running.

Comment: While this might be helpful, the question asks how to open Notepad++ by typing "Notepad" in a command line.